# Angular filter to replace a string in a 3d array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, replace, angularjs-filter

I can't seem to get this working.  I am trying to replace any empty space with letter "T" to convert my string to a date format but I can't seem to get it working.  My array works when I console.log and can see that it's yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm format. But when I put connect it with ng-repeat filter, it doesn't do anything.  Here's my code and link to the JSbin https://jsbin.com/nesedenoce/edit?html,js,console,output

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title>date filter</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="test" ng-controller="controller">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr id="theader">
      <thead>
        <th>Talk Title</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>End Time</th>
      </thead>
      </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in returnedObj  | dateFilter "> 
      <td>{{item.presentation.title}}</td>
      <td>{{item.presentation.start_time | date: "h:mm a"}}</td>    
      <td>{{item.presentation.end_time | date: "h:mm a"}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.controller("controller", ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.returnedObj = [{"presentation":{"title":"Introduction to Algebra",
                                      "persons":{"1":{"id":22,"start_time":"2017-05-19 08:00","end_time":"2017-05-19 08:20"},
                                      "speakers":[{"firstname":"Charles","lastname":"Hardin"}]}}}];
 }]);

  app.filter('dateFilter', function(){
        return function(item){
             var correctTimeFilter = item.filter(function(i){               
                if(i.presentation.start_time || i.presentation.end_time){           
                    console.log(i.presentation.start_time.replace(/\s/g, 'T'));
                    console.log(i.presentation.end_time.replace(/\s/g, 'T'));
                    return i.presentation.start_time.replace(/\s/g, 'T');
                    return i.presentation.end_time.replace(/\s/g, 'T');
                }
                else 
                    return null;
            })
            return correctTimeFilter;  
        }
    });
```

Comment: not clear why you need a filter on array for this. Also `start_time` is nested in `persons` object. Is only objective to parse date?

Comment: Note that would probably be easier to make `persons` an array also the way `speakers` is

Comment: I put `$scope.returnedObj` as an array here, but in my original code I am putting thousands of records that looks like that from PHP that was json_encoded.  But the format looks really similar to my original json string.

Comment: that doesn't answer question. Also, why isn't your php returning a valid date string?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading your object wrong. You are trying to get values from where they are not.

It is much cleaner when you format it like this:

```
$scope.returnedObj = [{
  "presentation":{
    "title":"Introduction to Algebra",
    "persons":{
      "1":{
        "id":22,"start_time":"2017-05-19 08:00","end_time":"2017-05-19 08:20"
      },
      "speakers":[{
        "firstname":"Charles","lastname":"Hardin"
      }]
    }
  }
}];
```

[Here](https://jsbin.com/kedehuwuxa/edit?html,js,output) is the snippet that does replace empty space in dates with `T` if that is what you wanted to do.

Also you can't return 2 values in sequence as you tried in filter function.